# MySQL : Unusual error concerning SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a bit of trouble with my ad function fo some reason. Umm everytime I press the submit button on the add form i get this error in plain english..

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable
>   English. Many desktop ' at line 2

Now I don't completely speak mysql so that is just jiberish to me. I was wondering if any of you can make sense of it for me. The code in quesion is highlighted with ** and ends with **. Also all the strtolower/htmlentities/strip_tags was my first attempt at preventing sql  injection and xss. Any help on that would be cool too. Thanks in in advance.

```
    $error = array();

//revalidate form in case javascript is disabled
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $title = strtolower(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['title'])));
    $price = strtolower(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['price'])));
    $location = strtolower(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['location'])));
    $cat = strtolower(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['list_one'])));
    $sub = strtolower(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['list_two'])));
    $description = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['description']));
    $email = strtolower(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['email'])));
    $password = strtolower(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['password'])));

    if(empty($title) || empty($price) || empty($location) || strcmp($cat,'none') == 0 
        || strcmp($sub,'none') == 0 || empty($description) || empty($email) || empty ($password)){
        $error[] = 'Please fill in the form!';
    }else if(!is_numeric($price)){
        $error[] = 'Price must be numeric!';
    }else if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', $title)){
        $error[] = 'Title must be alphanumeric!';
    }else if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $location)){
        $error[] = 'Location must be characters only!';
    }else if(strlen($location) > 17){
        $error[] = 'Your location may not be more than 17 characters!';
    }else if(!preg_match('/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/',$email)){
        $error[] = 'Your email is not in the correct format!';
    }else if(strlen($password) < 6){
        $error[] = 'Your password must be atleast 6 characters long!';
    }else{
                //no errors. check email and password match

        $hashPass = md5($password);

        $query_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($query_user) != 0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_user)){
                $user_id = $row['id'];
                $pass = $row['password'];
            }

            if(strcmp($hashPass,$pass) == 0){
                **$insert_ad = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ads(id,user_id,title,price,location,category,sub_category,description,dateCreated)
                    VALUES('','$user_id','$title','$price','$location','$cat','$sub','$description',CURRENT_DATE())") or die(mysql_error());**
            }else{
                $error[] = 'Your password didn\'t match the password in our system';
            }
        }else{
            $insert_user = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(id, email, password, vote_count) VALUES ('','$email','$hashPass', 0)") or die(mysql_error());
            $user_id = mysql_insert_id();
            **$insert_ad = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ads(id,user_id,title,price,location,category,sub_category,description, dateCreated)
                    VALUES ('', '$user_id', '$title', '$price', '$location', '$cat', '$sub', '$description', CURRENT_DATE())") or die(mysql_error());**
        }
    }

    if(!empty($error)){
        foreach($error as $key => $values){
            $error_message = "$values";
        }
        header('Location: add.php?error_with_add'.urlencode($error_message));
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Escape your values with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, or better yet, use prepared statements with parameters provided by `PDO` or `MySQLi` (the `mysql` extension is deprecated).

Comment: can you explain why that worked?

Comment: Well, there are some examples in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). If you read that (especially _"Example #2 An example SQL Injection Attack"_) & did not understand some of it, could you point to the specific portion you are unsure about?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you got that error is because you didn't escape your quotes. For example, this is what it would look like without escaping:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO foo (something) VALUES ('I'm really interested in coding here.')";
```

Note how the single quote was ended behind the I.

But when you escape the value with `mysql_real_escape_string`, or MySQLi, or PDO, it becomes like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO foo (something) VALUES ('I\'m really interested in coding here.')";
```

And, no error is shown, as the quote is escaped.